# Modern Libraries - Adding Locations to 'Move To' Selection

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, move, modern-experience, modern-document-library

So while the addition of 'Move To' in the Modern UI is a nice touch, it seems pretty limited by the fact it always takes the root of your selection as the current library, and only allows you to move items down from this point; no option for a 'sideways' move into another library, for example.

Is there a way to add other libraries to the Move To selector or is it stuck at only moving within the same library (for now, at least)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Move To is currently only available within the same document library. You can also move by dragging and dropping files to a sub-folder.

Microsoft has earlier announced support for move across sites. I quote ["Finally, we will also add the ability to move files, as well as copy files, among SharePoint Team sites as well as OneDrive sources."](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/Announcing-File-Copy-Move-for-SharePoint-Modern-Document/ba-p/4884)

I have not seen any announcements on the Move functionality since then.

Comment: Cheers, that's exactly what I was looking for. Nearly a year since that announcement tho, sigh.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to move the documents. Content and Structure in Site Settings can be used to move documents between different webs and libraries under same site collection. This is available for both SharePoint on premises and O365.

A sample from O365 SharePoint

[image]

Comment: Where is this available in SharePoint Online? It isn't in any visible menu, this started being deprecated as of SP2013.

Comment: The content and structure is in site settings. Please activate the publishing feature if it is not visible. The image in the answer is from current SharePoint online.